# Phonegap issue with deviceready event

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm working on a project for a hybrid mobile app. I used ripple during the build fase for testing and debugging. I used phonegap/cordova to build the apk for android, and this went well. Only now it seems like the the deviceready event is not triggered.

On login I use the following javascript code;

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {

  var email = $('#loginEmail');
  var password = $('#loginPassword');
  var base_url = $('#loginUrl');

  email.val(window.localStorage.getItem('ptu_email'));
  password.val(window.localStorage.getItem('ptu_password'));
  base_url.val(window.localStorage.getItem('ptu_url'));

  console.log(window.localStorage.getItem('ptu_url'));

  $('#loginForm').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $("#loginForm").validate();

    company.BaseUrl = base_url.val();
    company.LoginWithEmail(email.val(), password.val()).then(function() {
      window.location = 'dashboard.html';
    }, function(err) {
      console.log("Error:");
      console.log(err);
    });
  });
}, false);
```

This worked fine when using the ripple emulator but not with the apk installed on my galaxy s4. I looked at some other topics here, regarding issues with deviceready event but haven't find a solution yet. Anyone a idea whats going wrong here?

Comment: I recommend that you first make a test app using the `cordova create` command and run it on your device before adding *anything* else. Then try one thing at a time until you find the cause.

Comment: Do you see any output in the JavaScript console when running the app with the Chrome debugging tools attached?  You may need to force reload the app from the Chrome debugging tools by doing a page refresh in order to see the logs right from the start.  Alternately does anything useful come from attaching adb logcat to the device when you app is starting up on it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach.

`<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
          <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Device Ready</title>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script>
        function onLoad() {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', main, false);
        }
    </script>
      </head>
        <body onload="onLoad()">
        </body>
        <script>
        function main(){
        }
        </script>
        </html>`